# Jquery: Check if at least two checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to validate if at least two checkboxes are checked before submitting the data via ajax to the database.

Current Code: [How ever i do not get the alert]

```
$('#submit_button').on('click', function() {
   var interests = $("input[type='checkbox']");
      if (interests.is(":checked") >= 2) {
         var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function()   {return this.value}).get();
         alert("Valid");
      } 
      else 
      {
         $('._setupErrorHandler').show();
         $('#errorMessage').html("Please choose at least two interests")
      }
}
```

Comment: Missing `)` of `click` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use length:

```
if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length >= 2) {
```